# Textmate shortcut to format CSS with values lined up?

Tags: css, keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

**What's the Textmate shortcut to convert this:**

```
font: 13px 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
color: #333;
background: #3b3c3e url(/assets/bg-body.jpg);
padding: 18px 0 30px;
```

**Into this:**

```
font:         13px 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', sans-serif;
color:        #333;
background:   #3b3c3e url(/assets/bg-body.jpg);
padding:      18px 0 30px;
```

It has one for rails to do this for the = sign. Can't seem to find how to do it for colons.

Comment: "format CSS properly" - Sidebar, I actually think the former is easier to visually parse. I don't know there's anything "proper" about either way.

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Everyone has their own preference. Some of us find the latter more helpful was you can scan down the list of properties with faster readability.

Comment: That's true, I just wanted to state my piece about "properness". `;)`

Comment: I'm with @JaredFarrish on this one, easier to read. Although, the second one does look tidier. But I'm sure it is a preference.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [this bundle](https://github.com/sicher/align-tmbundle) in the past. I think there is another similar command, now, in the "source" bundle.

**EDIT**

Now that I'm on my Mac at work… The "Align Assignments" command found in the "Source" bundle doesn't work with colons. The "Align" bundle linked above is the way to go.

Comment: Just wanted to thank you for posting this comment. I have been searching for about two hours for an alignment bundle that would allow me to align my CSS declarations by the "{" leading curly brace. The align-tm bundle is the only I've been able to find that will do it!

Answer (score 1):

have a try with this. **Bundles > CSS > Format CSS or ^Q**
I don't know if it's working cause I don't use Textmate, I just googled it.

Comment: Tried that already, doesn't work :) It's only for alignment of the left most indentation